# Is there a way to merge duplicated rows and sum values on pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame (example):

| page_name | amount_spent |
| --- | --- |
| México opina | 50302 |
| De política | 49779 |
| El financiero | 72300 |
| México opina | 32000 |
| De política | 22000 |

I have been trying to make it look like this with `groupby` on Pandas unsuccesfully:

| page_name | amount_spent |
| --- | --- |
| México opina | 82302 |
| De política | 71779 |
| El financiero | 72300 |

This is that the duplicated rows on `page_name` merged, and the `amount_spent` in the merged rows were sum.

How can I achieve this on Pandas while creating a new DataFrame?

Comment: please provide `df.to_json()` for each of the data frames.

Comment: Groupby and sum? `groupby('page_name')['amount_spent'].sum()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `reset_index()`:

```
df_grouped = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('page_name')['amount_spent'].sum()).reset_index()
```

which will return a new `dataframe` as you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` and `sum`:

```
df.groupby(['page_name']).sum()
```